# project to which maximum number of employees have been allocated

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have these tables with the following columns :

```
Employee24 (EMPLOYEEID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, GENDER);

PROJECT24   (PROJECTID  PROJECTNAME EMPLOYEEID);
```

I want to write a query to find project to which maximum number of employees are alocated.

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME
 FROM EMPLOYEE24 E
  WHERE E.EMPLOYEEID IN ( SELECT L2.EMPLOYEEID 
                            FROM PROJECT24 L2 group by l2.employeeid)\\
```

Comment: Can you please post some sample data and desired result to clarify your question?

Comment: can you please elaborate? what you want to find?which project has more employees? can add some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to do if there are ties?  This is an important question and why `row_number()`/`rank()` might be a better choice:

```
select p.*
from (select p.projectid, p.projectname, count(*) as num_employees,
             rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from project25 p
      group by p.projectid, p.projectname
     ) p
where seqnum = 1;
```

Notes:

- The above query returns all rows if there are ties.  If you want only one (arbitrary) project when there is a tie, then use `row_number()`.
- I see no reason to join to `employee24`.
- Your data structure is strange.  The relationship between projects and employees should be in a separate table, say `project_employees`.  That should have `projectid`, but not the name.  The name should be in `project24`.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this (though I'm quite sure it can be done in other ways):

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT   prj.projectid,
                 prj.projectname,
                 COUNT(*) AS number_employees
        FROM     project24  prj
        JOIN     employee24 emp
          ON     prj.employeeid = emp.employeeid
        GROUP BY prj.projectid,
                 prj.projectname
        ORDER BY number_employees DESC)
WHERE  ROWNUM = 1;
```

Comment: No need for the join to `employee24`, works the same without, unless there's bad data :-)

Comment: @dnoeth: You're right. I'm just an old-fashioned puritan :-)